# Storing permanent value in Form while in validation handler

Tags: 6, forms

We can store a permanent value in `$form_state` in the submission handler, which will be retained against form errors, but I want to know how we can do it while in the validation handler, where I show an error using `form_set_error()`.

In short, I want to show an error in validation with the message "Press submit again to confirm". In this way, if the same form is submitted again it would skip the validation handler.

I can't do it in the submission handler, since it clears the values in the form.

`form_set_value()` is not able to retain a value.

**EDIT (on 28th Dec)**

I've found that $form_state['storage'] is works in validator also only if form_state['rebuild] is set to true. Infact this is how we use in submit handler. And if I call form_set_error in the validator form_state['rebuild] is simply ignored even if it is set and the storage value is not retained.

Comment: Did you try setting a value in `$form_state` from the validation handler?

Comment: You mean how we change and save it in submit handler? Yes it does not work.

Comment: No, I mean if you tried setting a value in `$form_state` from the validation handler, which is then checked in the validation handler when it is again called.

Comment: If I set a value in $form_state in validation handler then it is not retained when validation handler is called again after form_set_error and resubmit by user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$form_state['storage']` is probably what you're looking for. I've used it on multi-step forms myself to preserve necessary data that I need during various stages of the form processing. As an example you can define a storage variable like this:

```
$form_state['storage']['mykey'] = 'myval';
```

Edit:
Considering the additional information you provided it is indeed not quite as simple in your specific case. Setting `$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;` in the form validation handler also means that the user set form values will be lost. So what I think you could do is the following:

In the form validation handler function:

```
if (!isset($form_state['storage']['mykey'])) {
  $form_state['storage']['mykey'] = 'myval';
  // Save all the user set form values.
  foreach ($form_state['values'] as $key => $val) {
    // If you want to skip some values do it here.
    $form_state['storage']['values'][$key] = $val;
  }
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
  drupal_set_message('Press submit again to confirm');
}
```

In your form builder function use the stored values as defaults. Example:

```
$form['key_1'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#title' => t('Title'),
    '#options' => array(0,1,2),
    '#default_value' => $form_state['storage']['values']['key_1'],
);
```

Not sure how well the example code fits your needs, but it should get you started or at least give further ideas/options to try out.

Comment: That's what i've mentioned that I want to do it in validator and not in the submit handler.

Comment: This can be done in the validation handler and has worked out nicely for me so far.

Comment: In Drupal 7 is not anymore necessary to use `$form_state['storage']`, as reported in the documentation for [drupal_build_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/drupal_build_form/7): "`$form_state['storage']` is not a special key, and no specific support is provided for it in the Form API. By tradition it was the location where application-specific data was stored for communication between the submit, validation, and form builder functions, especially in a multi-step-style form." `$form_state['storage']` is used in Drupal 6.

Comment: @Dooshta where are you setting the value? In validation handler or submit handler?

Comment: Edited my answer, check if it helps you solve your problem now.

Comment: I don't want to use rebuild as user fed values will be lost

Answer (score 1):

The [Unique field](http://drupal.org/project/unique_field) module does something similar with respect to overriding form validation.  Grab its code and take a look to see if you can modify it to your needs.